# Ensure public key safety on deployed software

Tags: encryption, public-key-encryption, public-key, pki

I would like to ship my app to my client with my own public key. This key will be used when my clients need to export IP data from my app for debugging purposes. This data needs to only be readable by myself. Suppose that clients can not read my code and can not access my app's memory but would be able to identify my public key inside the app and maybe replace it with theirs thus making the exports readable by them. What options do I have to ensure that my public key is actually a pair for my own private key before commencing the export?

Comment: Store the public key *in the code*. If they can't read the code or access the process memory, how will they replace the key? And if they can, they can get to your exports even before they are encrypted.

Comment: I would like to avoid baking it in for various reasons. I set the supposition that users are not able to read/write the code such that safety checks are circumvented or data can not be read directly from memory in order to make things simpler (or maybe possibler). I imagine they can always run strings on my code which of course I could try to defeat by doing some more mangling inside my code but I would like to keep this one as a last resort option.

Comment: If the public key is not in the code (e. g. it's in a file or in a URL), then sign the public key with *another private key*, store the public key *for that one* in the code and verify the signature on the public key before use. That's how PKI trust trees work. You can even repurpose the X509 certificate machinery for that.

Comment: Your constraints are contradictory. If they cannot read your code then they cannot read the public key in your app, and if they cannot write your code then they cannot replace the key. But, as @Seva pointed out, hard-coding some public key in your code is how it's done. If every browser, OS, and computing environment can live with that constraint then chances are you can too.

Comment: @Polk: maybe the public key is in a file. Then the users will be able to spoof it even without going through the trouble of debugging the app.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev: My real point is that, no matter what answer you provide, OP will say it's not good enough.

Comment: Actually I'm ok with @SevaAlekseyev solution. I would have one more uncertainty. Suppose I only store the md5 hashed modulus of the public key in my app. Would it be safe to accept the actual key if it matches my baked in modulus?

Comment: I'd go with a better hashing algorithm, like SHA256. For MD5, there's a published exploit that finds a collision in ~30 minutes. That said, hash of a modulus is good enough. All public keys from legit sources that I've seen have the same public exponent anyway, 65537. The modulus pretty much identifies the key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If** we assume the OP's threat model, specifically that the attacker is not *debugging* the app and/or somehow messing with the process' memory in run time, **the app should validate the public key** before performing encryption, wherever the public key might come from.

In the order of diminishing strength:

- digital signature from a public certificate authority (it will be paid), rely on system trusted roots
- digital signature with another private key that the OP possesses (hard-code the public key in the app)
- HMAC of a public key with a hard-coded secret
- hash of a public key

In case of RSA keys, the modulus pretty much identifies the public key. The public exponent in most vendor implementations of RSA that I'm familiar with is hard-coded to 65537 anyway.